# scollIntoView() works with onload, but not if we arrive at site via link

Tags: javascript, onload, js-scrollintoview

Consider the following code:

```
    session_start();
    if (isset($_GET['anchor']))
    {
        $_SESSION['gotoanchor'] = $_GET['anchor'];
    } else if (!isset($_SESSION['gotoanchor']))
    {
        $_SESSION['gotoanchor'] = '';
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo "window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    let jumpsegmentname = 'anchor" . $_SESSION['gotoanchor'] . "';
    let jumpsegment = document.getElementById('anchor" . $_SESSION['gotoanchor'] . "');
        if (jumpsegment != null) {
            console.log('GO TO:' + jumpsegmentname); 
            document.getElementById(jumpsegmentname).scrollIntoView();  
        }
    })";
    echo '</script>';
```

And the following URL:

```
http://localhost/translateb.php?anchor=36
```

I am neatly transported if I arrive at this URL from another URL on the same server, or if I refresh said URL by pressing F5.

However, when I arrive at this URL from a link in an e-mail, the page does not scroll. The page is displayed, and I have to press F5 to actually arrive at the anchor.

When the page does not scroll, the console log (GO TO x) is displayed, where x has the correct number. Only scrollIntoView does nothing.

This is in Chrome. How come?

Comment: instead of `$_SESSION` you need to use `$_GET` for catch `anchor=36`

Comment: In the code before that, the value of $_GET is put into $_SESSION. I will clarify this.

Comment: We need to see this code too

Comment: Have you start session? `session_start();`

Comment: Yes, I have. Will add that too above.

Comment: Oh now i see the real problem, do you have an element with only id 32, but you can't have id with only number.

Comment: Actually with just id it always worked (from the browser's URL bar, but not via a link in e-mail), but I have now changed the code to use 'anchor' + id instead. However, I'm afraid this makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use only number into `id`, i test with `?anchor=test` like:

Correct code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['gotoanchor'] = (isset($_GET['anchor'])) ? $_GET['anchor'] : '';
?>

<div id='test'>ops</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let jumpsegment = document.getElementById('<?php echo $_SESSION['gotoanchor']; ?>');
        if (jumpsegment) {
            jumpsegment.scrollIntoView();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually with just id it always worked (from the browser's URL bar, but not via a link in e-mail), but I have now changed the code to use 'anchor' + id instead. However, I'm afraid this makes no difference.

Comment: I tested the code above in local, all work, so you have another problem we can't see

Comment: Can you give me a link for see problem?

Comment: That is very hard actually. This is part of a much bigger, quite confidential project. I can record a video if you want, but the most important question I think is: did you test this from a link in e-mail software? Because that it the only instance in which it doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't matter where link is, if is a good link `website.com?parameter=id` this code must work.

Comment: This suddenly started working. The only conclusion I can draw is that Chrome was behaving badly, as absolutely nothing has changed in the code. So you were right from the start: this should just work. Restarting the system solved the issue. I wish I could give you a thumbs up for this. Feel free to post this as an answer and I will do so.

Comment: Actually I think that in first instance, it didn't work. That adding text to the id did the trick, but that it took a restart for Chrome to actually pick it up (cache issues)?

Comment: _Feel free to post this as an answer_ is that an answer :D, for the problem 99% was cache problem for sure.

Comment: Done! Overlooked that. Once more thank you very much for your help.